# Modify the data in a column using subtraction

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

Currently I am writing a python code using pandas to read and modify the data in "User Time" column by subtraction. The csv file I am reading have a whole month data. At "User Time" all time data have been stored at one second interval. The values repeat itself after 1 week. But I want it to repeat after 1 day. So write this code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('out.csv')
x = df['User Time']


if 86400 < x.any() and x.any() > 172800:
    x = x - 86400
elif 172800 < x.any() and x.any() > 259200:
    x = x - 172800
elif 259200 < x.any() and x.any() > 345600:
    x = x - 259200
elif 345600 < x.any() and x.any() > 432000:
    x = x - 345600
elif 432000 < x.any() and x.any() > 518400:
    x = x - 432000
else:
    x = x - 518400

df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

There is no error, except all the values are subtract by 518400. The previous condition doesn't working.

I am new in python. Help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom function and change order of conditions from last to first, because in original solution always matched first condition:

```
np.random.seed(156)
df = pd.DataFrame({'User Time':np.random.randint(86400, 519400, size=10)})
#print (df)

def func(x):

    if (432000 < x) and (x < 518400):
        return x - 432000
    elif (345600 < x) and (x < 432000):
        return x - 345600
    elif (259200 < x) and (x < 345600):
        return x - 259200
    elif (172800 < x) and (x < 259200):
        return x - 172800
    elif (86400 < x) and (x < 172800):
        return x - 86400
    else:
        return x - 518400

df['new1'] = df['User Time'].apply(func)
df['new2'] = df['User Time'] - 86400
print (df)
   User Time   new1    new2
0     176044   3244   89644
1     257100  84300  170700
2     259874    674  173474
3     289963  30763  203563
4     474506  42506  388106
5     494801  62801  408401
6     399588  53988  313188
7     503743  71743  417343
8     344194  84994  257794
9     399799  54199  313399
```

Comment: I use this suggestion. This time all data is subtract by 86400.

Comment: @ArijeetSinha - Ya, you are right, so answer was edited also with data sample

Comment: As in the sample data, the 9th row in column User Time supposed to be subtracted by 345600. But it subtracted by 259200.

Comment: @ArijeetSinha - Really hard finding problem, but I got it - change conditions from `(432000 < x) and (x > 518400)` to `(432000 < x) and (x < 518400)` and similar for all elif